# MacBook Pro fan running full speed, activity monitor shows no computationally intensive applications

Tags: macbook-pro, cpu, temperature, activity-monitor

My 2018 Macbook Pro 15 inch fan is running at full speed all the time. I checked activity monitor and my idle was >95%. If this is a hardware problem, is there any way to fix it without opening up the whole computer? Otherwise, are there any easy fixes? Thanks

Comment: Since this is  a power/fan/temp related issue, the first thing to do is [reset the SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295)  Next, run in [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262) (Hold `Shift` while booting`) post your results.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. If no apps are shown, it is probably a background process. Activity Monitor can help you identity which background processes are having high CPU usage, see https://support.apple.com/HT201464 for more details.

Comment: have you seen a similar issue caused by excess activity from WindowServer?  I was trying to study the temperature and cant get the specific values using "sysctl -a | grep cpu"

Answer (score 1):

Like Allan said in the comments, try [resetting the SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295), or if you want to manually bring down your fan speed manually, try using [Macs Fan Control](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/47386/macs-fan-control) (this app can and will come in handy later in your life).